# Install Google Play on AndroidTV emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, android-tv

How to install the Google Play application on AndroidTV emulator in Android Studio? I know how to configure mobile emulator with Google Play, I just choose SDK with Google Play while configuring my emulator. But how to do that on AndroidTV emulator? Any workaround?